# discord.js Commando custom help command

Tags: discord, discord.js, commando

Is there any possible way to make the discord commando send a message in chat instead of dm's when doing the !help command for example.

I want to keep it with commando framework since it's easy to make commands with it and I like how you can do !help "command" and get details about that one command, but what I don't like is that it sends it all in to your dm's, and I want to have it in my discord server and some people have their dm's off too which is another problem. Is there any way to make it so that it sends in the normal chat instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable built in help command follow the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoRegistry?scrollTo=registerDefaultCommands) and build your own help commands
In case you need help commands source of commando is [here](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/02be96bc92ac3c982a5acc4f7e81e71bfd587c95/src/commands/util/help.js)

```js
bot.registry
  .registerDefaultTypes()
  .registerDefaultGroups()
  .registerDefaultCommands({
    help: true,
    prefix: false,
    eval: false,
    ping: true,
    commandState: false,
    unknownCommand: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously [you can specify the channel to send the command](https://discordjs.guide/commando/first-command.html#creating-your-command-class) in (DM is a channel too). The fact that you ask this question implies you have just started learning coding / using `discord.js`.

Stack Overflow is not your personal Google / won't write code for you, come back once you have actual questions (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to learn how to make good questions related to this site).

Enjoy your coding!